# Attaching jacoco agent to a running JVM

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

Two part question:

1) I have the requirement to attach the jacoco agent to an already running JVM, and per [this comment](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/715#issuecomment-407993661) on a Github issue, this was not possible as of 26th July 2018. Has support for this been implemented in the v0.8.5? Because the [changelogs](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html) do not mention it.

2) If I start a jacoco agent as such:

```
java -javaagent:jacocoagent.jar=dumponexit=false,output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6300 -jar my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Is it possible to gracefully kill the tcpserver that starts up **only** while keeping the jar running. I am looking for an alternative to having to writing a script that would need to look up the PID on port 6300 and kill the process. Preferably a jacoco cli command but the API Docs do not mention it.